# BOBTFISH/Task-Catalyst installation error

Tags: perl, centos, cpan, catalyst

I am using CentOS 5.7 perl 5.14.2. While installing CPAN module Task::Catalyst

```
cpan -i Task::Catalyst
```

i am getting the error:

http://pastebin.com/N1p1UMAH

3 modules `Catalyst::Authentication::Credential::HTTP`, `Catalyst::View::Email` and `Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store::DBIC` are giving installation errors

When i tried to manually install the modules , say Catalyst::View::Email
i downloaded the tar file, and then after running the ./Makefile.pl

i got the error

http://pastebin.com/ZSDLtqii

Please suggest?

Comment: i found that it's a [bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=83379) that is not fixed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Makefile.PL is just a perl script, that is generally invoked as `perl Makefile.PL`, and its output is a regular 'make' style `makefile`.

Have a look at its contents - perhaps it's been corrupted somehow. In the case of C::V::Email, it should be 39 lines long, and [look exactly like this](https://metacpan.org/source/DHOSS/Catalyst-View-Email-0.33/Makefile.PL).

Comment: mine and [your suggested](https://metacpan.org/source/DHOSS/Catalyst-View-Email-0.33/Makefile.PL) `Makefile.PL` both are identical.